# Sitefinity RadGrid not working in backend page

Tags: asp.net, sitefinity, sitefinity-4

I have a RadGrid on a sitefinity page, I am using it to create a module to proform CRUD on a database table in the backend.

If I put the RadGrid on a aspx page and view in browser, it works fine, However when I add it to a site finity back end page, Only the refresh and delete work, the add and update dont save to the database.

I can only assume something in the sitefinity backend if conflicting with the RadGrid Ajax

here is my code:

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="newsArticleAdmin.ascx.cs" Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.Modules.newsArticles.admin.newsArticleAdmin" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div id="adminContents">

<h2>News Articles</h2>
<p>These articles appear on the home page</p>
<br />


<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" Runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>


<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" />

                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="SqlDataSource1" />

            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>


    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True"
        AllowAutomaticInserts="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True"
        AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="True" AutoGenerateEditColumn="True" CellSpacing="0"
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="None" Skin="Telerik">


<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" CommandItemDisplay="TopAndBottom"
            DataKeyNames="fld_blogPostId" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            EditMode="InPlace">
<CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"
        AddNewRecordText="Add new article"></CommandItemSettings>

<RowIndicatorColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
</RowIndicatorColumn>

<ExpandCollapseColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
</ExpandCollapseColumn>

    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fld_blogPostId" DataType="System.Int32"
            FilterControlAltText="Filter fld_blogPostId column" HeaderText="fld_blogPostId"
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="fld_blogPostId" UniqueName="fld_blogPostId">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fld_blogTitle"
            FilterControlAltText="Filter fld_blogTitle column" HeaderText="fld_blogTitle"
            SortExpression="fld_blogTitle" UniqueName="fld_blogTitle">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fld_blogContents"
            FilterControlAltText="Filter fld_blogContents column"
            HeaderText="fld_blogContents" SortExpression="fld_blogContents"
            UniqueName="fld_blogContents">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fld_blogDate"
            FilterControlAltText="Filter fld_blogDate column" HeaderText="fld_blogDate"
            SortExpression="fld_blogDate" UniqueName="fld_blogDate">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fld_blogImage"
            FilterControlAltText="Filter fld_blogImage column" HeaderText="fld_blogImage"
            SortExpression="fld_blogImage" UniqueName="fld_blogImage">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>

<EditFormSettings>
<EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>
</EditFormSettings>
</MasterTableView>

        <StatusBarSettings LoadingText="Loading articles..."
            ReadyText="Articles ready" />

<FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu>

<HeaderContextMenu CssClass="GridContextMenu GridContextMenu_Default"></HeaderContextMenu>
    </telerik:RadGrid>


    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NewsArticlesConnectionString %>"
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tbl_newsArticles] WHERE [fld_blogPostId] = @fld_blogPostId"
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tbl_newsArticles] ([fld_blogTitle], [fld_blogContents], [fld_blogDate],
[fld_blogImage]) VALUES(@fld_blogTitle, @fld_blogContents, @fld_blogDate, @fld_blogImage)"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM tbl_newsArticles"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_newsArticles] SET [fld_blogTitle] = @fld_blogTitle, [fld_blogContents] = @fld_blogContents,
[fld_blogDate] = @fld_blogDate, [fld_blogImage] = @fld_blogImage WHERE fld_blogPostId = @fld_blogPostId">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogPostId" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogTitle" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogContents" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogImage" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogTitle" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogContents" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogDate" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogImage" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="fld_blogPostId" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>


</div>
```

Anyone seen this before and know of a fix?

Cheers

Andrew
@atmd83

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try opening the page in the backend page editor and make sure that "enable view state" is set to true. by default, backend pages in Sitefinity are usually set with this disabled, as most of the backend uses AJAX.

hope this is helpful!

Comment: Fantastic, works like a dream, I was checking the source and seeing viewstate but I guess thats the viewstate for the control and not the master page.